# Hebrew/English keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, hebrew

I need a keyboard manipulation to switch input language. 
I know how to switch by clicking on the desktop.

On Windows, we have <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

What is the equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> should work (<kbd>Super</kbd> is usually the key with Windows logo).